# Docusign Signer fields

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'll appreciate suggestions on how to get this achieved.

Goal:

Add additional field to the recipient section of a template.

Current State:
[image: Default recipient field].

The goal is to add an additional field for example, "Location", so there would be four input field instead of three as seen in the image.

I have tried playing around with the template Json but was not successful.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

I have tried to play around with the properties here but still no avail

```
"signers": [
      {
        "accessCode": "", 
        "agentCanEditEmail": "false", 
        "agentCanEditName": "false", 
        "completedCount": "0", 
        "defaultRecipient": "false", 
        "deliveryMethod": "email", 
        "email": "", 
        "inheritEmailNotificationConfiguration": "false", 
        "name": "", 
        "note": "", 
        "recipientId": "1", 
        "recipientIdGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
        "recipientType": "signer", 
        "requireIdLookup": "false", 
        "roleName": "verification Code", 
        "routingOrder": "1", 
        "signInEachLocation": "false", 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing in your screenshots is how the DocuSign web app sets up template's recipients. You cannot customize this expereince.

However, if what you want is to add meta-data to template recipients, you can do that by not using the DocuSign web app at all, instead you will build your own app, your own UI, and you can add any field, like location to the list.

Where would you store this information? you can use custom fields which is a means of having meta-data stores in DocuSign envelopes. There are different types of custom fields, and if you want them associated with template's recipients you may have to devise a system where they are created dynamically based on the recipients that the user added to their template.

So, say your user/customer created a template called "template1" and add a signer called "signer1" and you want to have their location, you will create a custom field called `template1_signer1_location` and create UI to enable your user to set the value for this custom field which will then be stored in the system for future retrieval.

What you do with this information is up to you and your app, but you'll have to build all of this capability, you will not be able to use the web app.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things. I am aware of the custom fields but that don't serve the purpose of this requirement. The requirement entails additional information from the signer/recipient of the envelop. So they would enter have to enter their name, email and location (requirement is to capture 3 information from the signer). The custom fields are useful for internal purposes only. I'll appreciate if you have any suggestions on how to achieve this. Hope I was able to make the intent clear.

Comment: Then I think all you need is text tabs in the envelope, the signers fill them up. Try it first manually to see if that is what you want. You can also have drop-down fields if you want them to select from a list of choices

Answer (score 0):

You can include a "location" text field in the document.

The signer would fill in the location field as a part of signing the document.

If you don't want the location field to be a part of the signed document, create a new document titled "Additional information" and use it for the location field.

Include both documents in the envelope